# Problem Translation word "Checkout"

Tags: magento2, localisation

I have a really strange problem.

Practically the word "Checkout" has disappeared both in the backend and in the frontend when I try to go to the checkout.
I think it's a translation problem, because en_US works fine in the store view.

But in the store view it_IT you present this bug.
How can I solve it?
I tried to delete the translation of the word "Checkout" but that doesn't change.

Magento 2.2.2 CE

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to search in all it_IT.csv on your site where the string `Checkout` were. Probably in it_IT language it was display as blank character.

Moreover take a look on translate inline table from database.

```
SELECT * FROM `translation` WHERE `string` LIKE '%checkout%'
```

Remove those lines which you find it as a problem.

Redeploy the static content, flush the cache.

Comment: I had checked all the it_IT.csv files but found nothing.

I totally forgot to look in the database!

I found an empty inline translation!
Once the table was removed, the problem was solved.

Thank you for your expertise.